# Node.js not show error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why when property in object not exist, node.js just die and not show any warning or error? How catch this error?

```
var element={};
var data=element.data.split('\n');
```

Comment: There should be an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` unless this is inside an exception handler that is catching the exception and handling it.

Comment: Yes should must be but not shows and it's very strange, tested on two different computers.

Comment: Show us the context for the code.  It must be inside of something else that is catching the exception then (like perhaps inside an async callback).  Running that code all by itself will throw a visible exception.

Answer (score 0):

use try catch

```
try {
    var element = {};
    var data = element.data.split('\n');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```